# Wordpress on Localhost. Reset site to beginning?

Tags: wordpress

I've got a localhost implementation of WordPress using xampplite for Windows.

I'd like to reset my site back to the way it was when I first installed wordpress (no posts, no settings, etc).

I need to do this so that I can test a base install against my wordpress theme updates.

Any help, much appreciated!

Perhaps i can just reset the options table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop all of your WP tables, IMO.  If you export them first you can restore the settings.  Or you can edit your WP configuration and change the table prefix.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to get an installation that will be exactly like the first time you installed would be to... re-install ; from the start -- which means with an empty database.

This will make sure everything is deleted : settings, posts, ... nothing will survive, if you drop all tables from your database.

That's what I generally do, in this kind of situation *(Even if it's generally not with wordpress, but with other software)*.

And if you really want to be 100% sure, you could also delete all the source files ; and re-download them -- to be sure there is nothing left from the previous installation.

Answer (score 1):

There's also a WordPress plugin for that...

The WordPress SQL Executioner @
http://justinsomnia.org/2008/02/the-wordpress-sql-executioner/